# Android String format - price

Tags: android

Is there an easy formatter to format my  String as a price?

So my string is: 300000 i'd like to "300 000" with space

```
or 1000000 "1 000 000"
```

Leslie

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Formatter class to format string

```
format("%,d", 1024);
```

After that replace , with space.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Have you really tried replacing the ',' with space? Though is seems obvious, but does not work

Comment: @Sarwar You cannot simply replace the `,` in formatter string. Using space there changes the meaning

Answer (score 31):

This does it:

```
String s = (String.format("%,d", 1000000)).replace(',', ' ');
```

Comment: this is the more appropriate and complete answer

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do this with a simple format string but with the `DecimalFormat` and `DecimalFormatSymbols` class.

```
int value = 123456789;
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols fmts = new DecimalFormatSymbols();

fmts.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

fmt.setGroupingSize(3);
fmt.setGroupingUsed(true);
fmt.setDecimalFormatSymbols(fmts);

TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText(fmt.format(value));
```

There are lots and lots of other options in these classes. For example you could seperate the numbers with dots or commas or use a locale specific setting.

For example you can use the `fmt.setCurrency` method:

```
fmt.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
double yourPrice = 1999999.99;
String formattedPrice = new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00€").format(yourPrice);
```

output :

formattedPrice = 1.999.99,99€

Answer (score 0):

if you have integer value, most elegant in my opinion

```
public static String formatNumberWithSpaces(long number) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    return formatter.format(number);
}
```